# System reminder to review the answers to your question

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer

I'd like a feature whereby I will be reminded to accept an answer to a question that I have asked. When I ask questions, I usually like to give them a day or so to collect answers before I choose an answer as the accepted one.

It would be good if I could tick a checkbox when asking a question to have SO/SF/SU remind me 24 hours later that I have a question that needs reviewing. This would purely be optional (similar to the "notify... daily of new answers" option), but would keep reminding me until I either accepted an answer or stated that I didn't want to. This would prevent me from forgetting about the question and never accepting an answer.

Comment: I can't figure out when it was implemented, but the profile now displays "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" for a month above old questions without accepted answers. I'd wager that your request is considered `[status-completed]`.

Comment: @PopularDemand A month is a far cry from the 24 hours the OP is suggesting...

Comment: @CamiloMartin, you misread, the questions don't have to be a month old. The message gets displayed for a month. I'm not sure how old the questions have to be, but I'm certain it's far less than a month.